# How to add days to a date with february leap year or not

Tags: java

I would like to know what are my mistakes in this code which I coded earlier and have problem testing it or it's incomplete, I want to add the month February specific days which has 28 days or 29 days (leap year or not)

```
  public void addDays(int x) {

    day = day + x;     
    if (day > 31) {     
      day = day - 31;   
      addMonths(1); 

    } else if (month == 2 && ((year % 400 == 0) || year % 4 == 0)) {
        day = day - 29;
        addMonths(1);

    }
```

add days wraps months,

add days wraps february non leap year,

add days wraps february leap year,

noting that I have already defined the variables day,month and year in another method as well as the other methods in the code and they work perfectly. Just having problem adding wraps for february leap year or not
Thanks.

P.S: I'm using this specific methods and classes because of the assignment requirements otherwise i would use the Calender class.

Comment: Why don't you simplify your life and use `java.util.Calendar` instead?

Comment: Is this java or javascript??

Comment: Sounds like Java, no "public void" in javascript

Comment: Some months only have 30 days.

Comment: The `public void` indicates java, or, at least, not javascript.
If you use the `java.util.Calender` objects, you will already have an `add` method, you can simply use. It will take care to change the month based on the real calendar

Comment: ok, because the code snippet is marked `lang-js`...

Comment: To build on what Mena answered: Why don't you keep your sanity and use `JodaTime` instead?

Comment: By the way, your code does not have the complete [Leap Year algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) for a Gregorian calendar. Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) rather than roll-your-own date-time library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class DaysAdder {

    int day=1;
    int month=1;
    int year=2014;

    public DaysAdder(int day, int month, int year) {
        super();
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public void addDays(int x) {

        day = day + x;
        if (day > 29 && month == 2 && isLeapYear()) {
            day = day - 29;
            addMonths(1);
        } else if (day > 28 && month == 2 && !isLeapYear()) {
            day = day - 28;
            addMonths(1);
        } else if (day > 30 && !is31dayMonth()) {
            day = day - 30;
            addMonths(1);
        } else if (day > 31 && is31dayMonth()) {
            day = day - 31;
            addMonths(1);
        }
    }

    private boolean is31dayMonth() {
        List<Integer> month31 = Arrays.asList(1,3,5,7,8,10,12);
        return month31.contains(month);
    }

    private boolean isLeapYear() {
        return ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0);
    }

    private void addMonths(int i) {
        month = month + i;
        if (month >= 13) {
            addYear(1);
            month = month - 12;
        }
    }

    private void addYear(int i) {
        year = year + i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DaysAdder [day=" + day + ", month=" + month + ", year=" + year
                + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DaysAdder daysAdder = new DaysAdder(23, 2, 2016);
        daysAdder.addDays(7);
        System.out.println(daysAdder); //DaysAdder [day=1, month=3, year=2016]
        daysAdder = new DaysAdder(23, 2, 2014);
        daysAdder.addDays(7);
        System.out.println(daysAdder); //DaysAdder [day=2, month=3, year=2014]
    }
}
```